# Cancel a cronjob or an automatically loaded process on OS X

Tags: macos, crontab, launchd

I'm currently being bugged by Mail.app popping open every friday at the same time and simultaniously I receive mails from an app iBackup which I used to have installed.

I would like to get rid of it for good but I can't find the process or cronjob that launches Mail.app.

Things I tried:

- Terminal

  - `crontab -l`
  - `sudo crontab -l`
  - `for user in $(dscl . list /users); do sudo crontab -u $user -l; done`
- Searched all available locations listed by `man launchd` for a reference to Mail (grepped)

Where are crontabs listed in OS X? Are there any other places I can search for a script that launches every friday at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Mac OS X still has `cron`, since Tiger (10.4) the preferred program for automatically starting processes is `launchd`. It replaces `cron`, `init`, `watchdogd` and others. A well-written and reasonably recent Mac program would be expected to use `launchd` rather than `cron` for scheduling a periodic job.

[This article](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20050620071558293) is a good overview, but to address your problem more directly, have a look in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons` for `launchd` property lists. These property lists are generally named in a reverse-domain fashion, so `com.ibackup.ibackup.plist` would be a good thing to start looking for. Once you find the offending file(s) do `[sudo] launchctl unload /path/to/file` to deactivate it. Move or delete it to prevent it being automatically reloaded on reboot.

Comment: Are there any ways to see the scheduling for these jobs? I've already grepped these directories (listed by `man launchd` for the strings ibackup and mail but no success. Maybe i can trace it down by filtering on the time the scripts are run?

Comment: `Launchd` jobs can be run in response to a number of things, but those that run after a certain interval will contain `<key>StartInterval</key>` while those which run at a particular time will have `<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>` somewhere in them. Look at some of the Apple property lists in the same folders for examples of usage.